# ERROR: Duplicate alias. Failed to register servlet for - Eclipse Scout error on RAP

Tags: java, eclipse, servlet-filters, eclipse-scout

I have error when I run RAP version of eclipse scout apllication...?

```html
2015-03-23 09:32:50.409:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2015-03-23 09:32:50.463:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8082
ERROR: Duplicate alias. Failed to register servlet for [alias="/", contributor="com.rinels.eambulancecentral.ui.rap[26]"]
```

That servlet is registered for:

```
org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.mobile.servlets.DeviceDispatcherServlet
```

I dont know where the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to reproce this error by having 2 servlets registered for the same alias.

Here an example producing the ERROR:
[image: Plug-in Editor]

(`plugin.xml` file is located at the root of the rap bundle: `<your app>.ui.rap`)

```
ERROR: Duplicate alias. Failed to register servlet for [alias="/", contributor="<myapp>.ui.rap[7]"]
```

You can also display the XML content as text (`plugin.xml` Tab of the Plugin editor or any text editor). Search for the extension point `org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets` you should find one or two snippets like this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets">
   <!--servlets are defined here-->
</extension>
```

Of course, if you have multiple bunldes contributing servlets started in your application, this also generates a conflict.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But I have only one servlet for ne allias in RAP plugin XML.<extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets">
    <servlet
      alias="/"
      class="org.eclipse.scout.rt.ui.rap.mobile.servlets.DeviceDispatcherServlet">
    </servlet>
  </extension>

Comment: As I wrote it, my guess is that the conflict comes from multiple bundles contributing a `servlet`. You should look in all your `plugin.xml` files.